# Logistic random effect model

Tags: mixed-model

I have a dataset with measurements of three variables for each ear. The dependent variable is binary and I want to see which of the variables are related to the outcome. Thus, there are two rows for each individual; one for the right and one for the left ear, and either the left OR the right Outcome is always 1.

```
Id - Side - VarA - VarB - VarC - Outcome
```

My advisor claims I should do a logistic mixed model clustered by Id. Is this correct? Just intuition leads me to think that the expected outcome will be .5 and hence that the variance between individuals is close to 0 and thus there is nothing to model at this level or have I misunderstood the concept of mixed effects modeling?